# Completeness relation and expansion theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

Why is $$\sum_a u_a(y)u_a^*(x)=\delta(x-y)$$ (the completeness relation) equivalent to saying that for any arbitrary $f(x)$ s.t. $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f(x)| = 1$, $f(x)$ can be expanded as $$\sum_ac_au_a(x)$$, where $c_a$'s are constants (the expansion theorem)?

Thanks.

***Symbols:***

{$u_a(x)$} are orthonormal eigenfunctions

$\delta(x-y)$ is the Dirac delta function

Comment: Would you please specify what your symbols mean?

Comment: Sure, specification added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any such $f(x)$, multiply both sides by $f(x)$ and integrate with respect to $x$, doing the left hand side term by term. You obtain 
$$\sum_a c_a u_a(y) = f(y)$$
Here $c_a = \int f(x)u_a^*(x)\,dx$.

Comment: Thanks! I am having a brain-dead day... sigh...